# Objective-C/Cocoa: get key code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hotkeys, nstextfield, keycode

hi
to set my applications hotkeys i need to convert a character into its keycode. how is that possible?

i have multiple checkboxes for the modifier keys and a small textfield for the key. but im sure i saw textfields which display the whole key combination which is pressed...
because i didnt find anything i took a simple textfield. so now i need the key code of the char in this field.

(my idea: my own nstextview, overwrite keydown or keyup and get the [event keycode] or something similar. but i want to use a textfield!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Shortcut Recorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/).  It's a control you can use in your interfaces for recording keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: hmm i dont think i can get that mammoth to work (i cant even build it, xcode says:"the selected run destination is not valid for this action"?), and i cant really find a demo/tutorial how to use it

Comment: Project is not there in the above link

Comment: @ThE uSeFuL: there's a nice big link to "Get the latest version from the Shortcut Recorder Google Code project"...

Answer (score 3):

There is a small application called [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) that should do what you want.